# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [...] with qualifiers [@Named]

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-8

I can deploy and run the project successfully, however, when I try to run the Test method. I had this common error

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [AutomatedTellerMachine] with qualifiers [@Named] at injection point [[field] @Named @Inject private advocacy.TestExample.automatedTellerMachine]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:243)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:106)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:126)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:345)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:330)
..
..
```

Also I have read similar questions from here nothing did help. I was reading some helloword examples about dependency injection from here [cdi-tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/wiki/DependencyInjectionAnIntroductoryTutorial_Part1#META-INF/beans.xml) and after that I have started to read [arquillian-tutorial](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/).

**AutomatedTellerMachine.java**

```
package advocacy;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public interface AutomatedTellerMachine {

    public void deposit(BigDecimal bd);
    public void withdraw(BigDecimal bd);
}
```

**AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.java**

```
package advocacy;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Named("atm")
public class AutomatedTellerMachineImpl implements AutomatedTellerMachine {

    @Inject
    @Named("jsonRestAtmTransport")
    private ATMTransport atmTransport;

    ...
}
```

and my test method is like;

**TestExample.java**

```
package advocacy;

imports..

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestExample {

    @Inject
    @Named("atm")
    private AutomatedTellerMachine automatedTellerMachine;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "dependecy-injection.war")
                .addClasses(AutomatedTellerMachine.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "META-INF/beans.xml");
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        automatedTellerMachine.deposit(new BigDecimal(12.99));
    }
}
```

my beans.xml is in `src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml`

Finally, you can see my pom.xml file [here](http://pastebin.com/cnG0M1DJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.class` to `ShrinkWrap`, like that:

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "dependecy-injection.war")
            .addClasses(AutomatedTellerMachine.class)
            .addClasses(AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "META-INF/beans.xml");
}
```

In practice it is better to add directly a package, so you do not miss all the time something.